# How to change orientation of iPhone on button click?

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation

I've been searching through lots of posts trying to find a way to change the orientation of the view manually. However I can't seem to find a definitive answer that's not outdated. Please can someone suggest the best way to switch the orientation based on when a user presses a button?

I.e. I need some help filling in the gap...

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // Switch the orientation to ...
}
```

Comment: You should not do this, since it not logica and the user will not understand why it should hold its device an other way.

Comment: For the record, there are definitely use cases where it is reasonable to want to do this, particularly with motion-based apps where letting the device rotate spontaneously would ruin the UX but where being able to change it on command makes sense and is useful to the end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple guideline doesn't allow that. There's some hack to do that but it's not a good idea to use it.

Your app will run in a real device and there isn't any piece of code that can physically turn the phone. Device orientation is constraint by real world constraint, you can't force your user to turn his phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

Change the orientation to Landscape or Portrait.

You might have to also apply a transformation to complete the change:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.view.transform, -(M_PI / 2.0));
```